# Apache Handles PHP Array Tag as closing Tag

Tags: php, linux, apache, php-7, web-development-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTzDe.png)I did a PHP-Project on my Windows Localhost **XAMPP**. Now I wanna launch it on the companies Linux Server on Apache2.4 BUT somehow this Apache handles the Array Part (=>) as the closing tag for `php`. How to fix this? 
Thanks for your applys in advance!

```
<?php

    $error = "";
    if(isset($_POST['username'],$_POST['password'])){
        $user = array('usern' =>'xxx',"passw"=>"yyy",);
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $pass = $_POST['password'];
        if($username == $user['usern'] && $pass == $user['passw']){
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['simple_login'] = $username;
            echo '{"error":0}';
        }else{
            echo '{"error":1}';
        }
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Can you please share the error?

Comment: Seems like `php` is not installed . As well as code enhancement:- https://3v4l.org/vVpCO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you describe it, it seems that the code is interpreted as html.

It is most likely that php module for apache is not installed on the webserver.

Comment: You are right! $ sudo apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php made it work! Thank you very much!